# Magento2 Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page while creating configurable product

Tags: php, configuration, magento2, ini

While creating the configuration products in magento2.2.2 I am facing the **“Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page”** error. I have google regarding this error and I have found the solution to `increase the value of max_input_vars PHP configurable variable`. I have increased this value but the problem is not solved.

**While creating the configurable product almost 40000 associated product is generated and now I have set the max_input_vars value to 3075000 but the problem is not solved.**

Anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Honestly, i don't think you will be able to create 40001 products in
   just one time.
2. Then, associate 40000 products to a configurable one from admin
   product page, looks also something hard.

**If you have developper skills, I recommend you to script all of this.**
Programatically create products is easy.

Btw, you will need to increase php `max_excecution_time` if you script don't use PHP Cli (When you run php command line, or CRON, there will be no maximum execution time.)

Usually, i run thoses scripts from Magento CRON to keep a 2mn php `max_excecution_time`.

Comment: I am new to Magento2 can you please provide me any hint how to process all this 40K associative product via script.

Comment: Ok. I think I finded some good process for you. Have you try this Magento 2 feature ? https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/magento-2-import-configurable-products.html

Comment: Hm. It's very weird : this import page only contains a few input fields. Your problem doesn't seem to be related to `max_input_var` php option, but related to form_key or session. Are you working with `http://localhost/` url ? Have you tried with Chrome AND Firefox ? If you are using Redis, can you flush it ? If you are not using Redis, can you empty the var/session folder please ?

Comment: I have tried on both localhost & server. Also I have tried on Chrome, firefox normal as well as private window. and before start this I have also clear the var/ session, var/cache, var/page_cache folders. But same problem :(

Comment: OK, next questions :) Can you paste a phpinfo();die; at the top your pub/index.php file please ? Then tell me values of : `max_file_uploads`, `max_input_vars` and `post_max_size` please ?

Comment: please check php configuration value `max_file_uploads = 20, max_input_vars=3075000, post_max_size = 32M`

Answer (score 0):

40,000 variations on configurable product will take too long to load on the admin, besides, are you displaying 40,000 options on frontend to the customer? I suggest you review your solution on this, this is a design issue.

Comment: Yes we need all this 40K options in fronend for this we have already created the custom design.

Comment: Then probably just create them via a script, a cron or console. Then when create the configurable product use an observer or plugin to assign them to it. Also you will face a browser crash when loading the product page if it has 40,000 variations so  I think not to load them from admin on the product edit page on that particular product.